# How laravel set path for ajax and forms

Tags: ajax, forms, laravel, path

I have simple question:
How laravel set correct path for ajax or form action?

I have my laravel instalation in

localhost/laravel-test/public

Ok and lets say i have url opened: localhost/laravel-test/public/hello

```
<form method="post" action="some/very/long/path">
        <input type="submit" value="just-test" />
</form>
```

Now i hit just-test button, and its always know where it should start routing - allways start from public/[route here].

I was try to do my own routing system, but i have problem because its going to addres:

```
localhost/my-framework/public/hello/some/very/long/path
```

It allways put after public my actual url, and then after form action..

So my question is how laravel know it should get

```
localhost/laravel-test/public/some/very/long/path
```

It works same for jquery ajax request for ex:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
})
```

Laravel console output:

```
localhost/laravel-test/public/test.html
```

My custom framework console output

```
localhost/my-framework/public/actualpath/test.html
```

Answer (score 2):

For the form action you can use the **url** or **route** helper. Like so:

```
{{ url('very/long/path') }}
```

And for your front end part.

```
$('#form').live('submit', function(event) {
    $form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for.

*In `routes.php`*

```
Route::post('some-very-long-uri', ['as' => your-name', 'uses' => 'YourController@method']);
```

Then you can do something like that

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('your-name') }}">
    <input type="submit" value="just-test" />
</form>
```

and for ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('your-name') }}"
});
```